Exception in thread "Loader for _view_0": java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ice.pilots.html4.ThePilot.setKeyHandler(Ljava/awt/event/KeyAdapter;)V
I am using SPM in matlab2021b, my version is macOS14, something seems to go wrong.
SPM do work but always hard to run. I have already downloaded the java 8, but it seems not to work.
Here is the error information:


Exception in thread "Loader for _view_0": java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ice.pilots.html4.ThePilot.setKeyHandler(Ljava/awt/event/KeyAdapter;)V
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.html.ICERenderer$MyPropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(ICERenderer.java:1455)
    at ice.storm.StormBase.add(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.StormBase.sendViewportMessage(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.StormBase.append(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.StormBase.do_clear_content(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.StormBase.do_render_content(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.Viewport.runAsynchronousLoad(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.LoadThread.run(OEAB)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0": java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ice.pilots.html4.ThePilot.setCursorChangeable(Z)V
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.html.ICERenderer.setWaitCursor(ICERenderer.java:1813)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.html.ICERenderer.finishedLoading(ICERenderer.java:1685)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.html.ICERenderer.access$2400(ICERenderer.java:107)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.html.ICERenderer$MyPropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(ICERenderer.java:1552)
    at ice.storm.StormBase.add(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.StormBase.sendViewportMessage(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.Pilot.firePropertyChange(OEAB)
    at ice.pilots.html4.ObjectPool.OEAB(OEAB)
    at ice.pilots.html4.ObjectPool.fireOutstandingImagesEvent(OEAB)
    at ice.pilots.html4.ThePilot.onLoadingDone(OEAB)
    at ice.storm.Viewport$2.run(OEAB)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)```

I want to solve the problem.

